# Select avançado sql

Tags: mysql

Gostaria que a coluna id_post_gru fosse preenchida de 2 baseado na quantidade de id_grupo onde existe 70

Fiz isso separadamente e funciona, porém juntos não!

```
UPDATE
  posts
SET
  id_post_gru =(
  SELECT
    COUNT(id_grupo)
  FROM
    posts
  WHERE
    id_grupo = 70
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione a cláusula **GROUP BY** ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
UPDATE posts 
    SET id_post_gru = (
        SELECT COUNT(id_grupo) 
        FROM posts WHERE id_grupo = 70
        GROUP BY id_group
    );
```